# How to create an infix to postfix using two stacks

Tags: java, data-structures, infix-notation

I need to use **two** stacks to evaluate an infix into a postfix expression. One stack is to hold all of the operands and the other stack is to hold all of the operators.

1. An operand is either the first or second operand for an operator. If the operator
   stack is empty or if a left parenthesis is on top of the stack, the operand is the first
   operand for an operator. Push the operand onto the operand stack. Otherwise, the
   operand is the second operand for an operator. The first operand should be on top of
   the operand stack, and the operator should be on top of the operator stack. Pop the
   first operand and the operator from the stacks, and form the postfix expression
   representing applying the operator to its two operands. This expression is an operand
   to which another operator may be applied, so push it onto the operand stack.
2. A right parenthesis marks the end of an infix operand expression. The matching left
   parenthesis should be on top of the operator stack, and the postfix operand expression
   corresponding to the infix operand expression should be on top of the operand stack.
   Pop the left parenthesis off the operator stack. If the stack is now empty or if the token
   on top of the stack is another left parenthesis, the operand on top of the operand stack
   is the first operand for an operator, assuming the end of the whole infix expression has
   not been reached. In this case, do nothing further. Otherwise, the postfix expression
   on top of the operand stack is the second operand for an operator. The first operand
   should be immediately below it, and the operator should be on top of the operator stack.
   Pop both operands and the operator from the stacks, and form the postfix expression
   representing applying the operator to its operands. As in 1 above, push this expression
   onto the operand stack.
3. To process an operator or a left parenthesis, simply push it onto the operator stack.
   Easy.
   After the last infix token has been processed, the operator stack should be empty and
   the operand stack should contain a single postfix expression. It is the postfix
   expression corresponding to the infix expression.

I am stuck on what to do next. Here is what I have so far. I want to break this down into pieces so it is easier to manage.

```
    /**
 * Evaluates the specified postfix expression. If an operand is encountered,
 * it is pushed onto the stack. If an operator is encountered, two operands
 * are popped, the operation is evaluated, and the result is pushed onto the
 * stack.
 * 
 * @param expr
 *            string representation of a postfix expression
 * @return value of the given expression
 */
public String evaluate(String expr) {
    // A variable to hold the resulting postfix expression
    String result;
    // A variable to hold individual tokens in the infix expression
    String token;
    // Scanner to read the users input expression
    Scanner parser = new Scanner(expr);
    // Variables to hold the first and second operands
    String op1, op2;

    // Reading the input one character at a time
    while (parser.hasNext()) {
        token = parser.next();

        // Performing postfix calculations

        // Pushing values on the stacks
        if (token.equals("(")) {
            operatorStack.push(token);
        } 
        else if (!isOperator(token)){
            operandStack.push(token);
        }
        else{
            operatorStack.push(token);
        }

        //Part 1 
        if (operatorStack.isEmpty() || operatorStack.peek().equals("(")){
            operandStack.push(token);
        }
        else{
            op2 = (operandStack.peek());
        }


    }
```

Comment: Scanner tokenizes on whitespace by default...  You're going to have trouble with something like `((7*2) +5) /2` coming back as 3 tokens.

Comment: I know spaces between the input is what I am planning on doing